# Is it possible to move an icon using negative margins to the middle of the line

Tags: css

I want to create a timeline, is it possible to move this icon to the middle of the line?

I have a list of items with a border-left on the list:

```
.blah {
  list-style: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I want the icon to be in the middle of the border line.  So the image will hover above the line, and fit exactly in the middle.

```
<ul class="blah">
<li>
    <div class="blah--icon">
      <svg height="16" class="octicon octicon-clock mr-1" aria-label="clock" viewBox="0 0 14 16" version="1.1" width="14" role="img"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 8h3v2H7c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V4h2v4zM7 2.3c3.14 0 5.7 2.56 5.7 5.7s-2.56 5.7-5.7 5.7A5.71 5.71 0 0 1 1.3 8c0-3.14 2.56-5.7 5.7-5.7zM7 1C3.14 1 0 4.14 0 8s3.14 7 7 7 7-3.14 7-7-3.14-7-7-7z"></path></svg>
    </div>
    hello world
</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8yz9nLu0/6/

Can this icon be in the middle regardless of the screen width? i.e. it should be responsive so it doesn't get off center if the browser window changes etc.

Comment: why negative margin precisly ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have to somehow push the icon to the left, I thought I would need negative margins for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead of negative margin:

```css
.blah {
   list-style: none;
   border-left: 1px solid #000;
   position:relative; /*added*/
}
.blah--icon {
  position:absolute;
  left:-7px;
  top:calc(50% - 8px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="blah">
<li><div class="blah--icon">
    <svg height="16" class="octicon octicon-clock mr-1" aria-label="clock" viewBox="0 0 14 16" version="1.1" width="14" role="img"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 8h3v2H7c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V4h2v4zM7 2.3c3.14 0 5.7 2.56 5.7 5.7s-2.56 5.7-5.7 5.7A5.71 5.71 0 0 1 1.3 8c0-3.14 2.56-5.7 5.7-5.7zM7 1C3.14 1 0 4.14 0 8s3.14 7 7 7 7-3.14 7-7-3.14-7-7-7z"></path></svg>
</div>hello world</li>
<li>this is fun</li>
<li>learn you some css negative margins</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so the blah--icon is absolute, but relative to its parent?

Comment: @Blankman not its parent (li) but its grand parent (ul) and this is the important part here since the border belong to ul and that's why we need relative inside ul and not li

Comment: I see, so now I need to make the icon'z zindex higher right?

Comment: @Blankman it depends if you have more elements .. actually without z-index the icon is already above the line (add a background to see)